# Regarding Installing and Using Techminer Package

Tags: python, user-interface

I have installed `techminer` package and its dependencies. The `techminer` app starts but I cannot see any option for functionality. Only a drop down list is displayed but no functions. Please advise.

```
pip install techminer

from techminer.app import App
App().run()
```

I was expecting a functional GUI which is a `bibliometric` analysis tool.

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/jdvelasq/techminer) says you have to execute that in *a cell of Jupiter Lab or Google Colaboratory* with Python 3.6. How did you run your code?

Comment: Note that this is not a programming question.  It is really about how to *run a tool* that doesn't appear to be a programming tool.